# Can't get implementation of hill climb algorithm for solving ciphers to work

Tags: python, algorithm

I found a hill climb algorithm for solving monoalphabetic substitution ciphers in a paper and have tried implementing it in Python. The algorithm isn't really that complicated but I still can't get it to work. No meaningful results are generated even with very long ciphertexts, which according to the author should have a 90+ % success rate (i.e. 90% of letters correct compared to known plaintext). These are the results to expect according to the paper:

[image: Percentage solved]

This is the full description of the algorithm in pseudocode:

[image]

Assuming all the bits I import from `functions` are correct (this is actually a simple testcase from a much larger project where I have extensive tests for each function), can anyone spot any obvious errors in the code below?

(A full, self-contained version that you can run yourself is [here](https://pastebin.com/dLX9wfkn).)

```python
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase

import numpy as np
from functions import _get_digram_frequencies, _get_plaintext, _score, _swap

ciphertext = (
    "uknkgmhksztkmexmpbxtgxesxekeskvuakgluepbhvpmhhpvxtwhphmvydmrbuthhgkfxgse"
    "xmpbhmeymhhohwgkzdwxenzfbhhlvabufbymkfhvnzehmihvkestuggvnhaupbshgurbpsxz"
    "xddeshmvpkespbuvthhguerpbuvymhhohabufbbkvpmkihgghstmxnpbhmhruxevpxakmsva"
    "bufbuknksikefuerruihvnhktxmhpkvphxtpbxvhufzfgunhvuevwumuphsyzpbuvauesxtw"
    "mxnuvhnzskzs"
)

print(f"\nCiphertext:\n{ciphertext}")

# Initial key is the letters in the ciphertext in order of most common first, and with
# remaining letters (not present in ciphertext) added at the end.
c = Counter(ciphertext)
key = [letter[0] for letter in c.most_common()]

for c in ascii_lowercase:
    if c not in key:
        key += c

print(f"\nInitial Key:\n{''.join(key)}")

# Algorithm starts here.

putative_plaintext = _get_plaintext(ciphertext, key)
digram_frequencies = _get_digram_frequencies(putative_plaintext)

best_score = _score(digram_frequencies)
print(f"\nInitial score is {best_score}")
print("Starting climb algorithm\n")

for i in range(1, 26):
    for j in range(26 - i):
        d = np.copy(digram_frequencies)
        _swap(d, j, j + i)
        score = _score(d)
        if score < best_score:
            digram_frequencies = np.copy(d)
            key[j], key[j + i] = key[j + i], key[j]
            best_score = score
            print(f"Got new best score {score:.02f} and key is now {''.join(key)}")

print(f"\nFinal Key:\n{''.join(key)}")

plaintext = _get_plaintext(ciphertext, key)

print(f"\nPlaintext:\n{plaintext}\n")
```

Comment: An example run is here: https://pastebin.com/63ghJwLw One thing I notice is that the score doesn't drop very fast, which could be why some of the more drastic swaps are accepted later in the algorithm even though they potentially result in worse results. That the threshold is too small for swaps to make a meaningful difference.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "very long ciphertexts". The 300 character example is not long at all, considering that there are 676 possible digrams. The other problem is that the lack of spaces between words will create false digrams. For example, if the text is about [Tariq Trotter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Thought) and contains phrases like "tariq quietly", "tariq quickly", or "tariq queried", you'll get hits for the `qq` digram, which normally should have zero probability.

Comment: @user3386109 I have tried it on ciphertexts up to 10,000 chars long with little improvement in results. Good suggestion about false digrams, I will modify the generation of the digram frequencies matrix to see if anything changes. I do wonder though why tools like https://www.dcode.fr/monoalphabetic-substitution and https://github.com/alimony/homophonic-cipher-attack manage to solve these even without spaces.

Comment: @user3386109 Taking spaces into account made a negligible difference, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved this yesterday. The problem was that the digram matrices, both the constant English one and the one calculated from the ciphertext, were constructed using alphabetical order, meaning element (0, 0) for "aa", (0, 1) for "ab" and so on. This would not work since the initial key is in most common order, and the equivalence of the matrix swaps and key swaps is only valid if they match up to begin with. So the correct order to use for the digram matrices is most common in English first, meaning (0, 0) for "ee", (0, 1) for "et" and so on.